# how to translate date properly in angular 6

Tags: angular, localization

I included `registerLocaleData(localBn)`. where localBn imported from  `'@angular/common/locales/bn'`

using angular date pipe in component `{{dateObj | date:'longDate':'':'bn'}}`
It's only translating the MONTH name but day or year numeric values stay in the English.

for example, 2018-01-01 currently translating to 1 জানুয়ারি 2018;

how can I achieve this translation that change the numeric day and year too? (১ জানুয়ারি ২০১৮)